# Problema con ListView al iniciar la aplicación

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist, android-listview

Estoy creando una aplicación en *Android Studio* que utiliza `ListView` en el `MainActivity` y se llena desde un *Activity* secundario que sale cuando toco un botón "agregar". El detalle es que al momento de iniciar la aplicación de una vez me salta el error de **Se ha detenido** y automáticamente se cierra. 
Estoy usando 2 `ListView`, ya que una es para `saldosNegativos` y la otra para `saldosPositivos`. Aquí dejo el código de las dos clases que estoy utilizando para saber si me pueden corregir.

Este es el `MainActivity`:

```
public class PaginaInicio extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pagina_inicio);

    Button agregarSaldo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonNuevoSaldo);
    ListView listaSaldosPositivos = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewSaldoPositivo);
    ListView listaSaldosNegativos = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewSaldoNegativo);
    TextView totalSaldo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textSaldoTotal);

    agregarSaldo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent irASaldo = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),nuevoSaldo.class);
            startActivity(irASaldo);
        }

    });

        ArrayList<Saldo> elSaldoPositivoQueLlego = (ArrayList<Saldo>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("saldosPositivos");
        ArrayList<Saldo> elSaldoNegativoQueLlego = (ArrayList<Saldo>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("saldosNegativos");
        double resultado = 0;
        double resultado2 = 0;

    if(elSaldoPositivoQueLlego!=null || elSaldoNegativoQueLlego!=null) {
        String[] montosPositivos = new String[elSaldoPositivoQueLlego.size()];
        String[] montosNegativos = new String[elSaldoNegativoQueLlego.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < elSaldoPositivoQueLlego.size(); i++) {
            double monto = elSaldoPositivoQueLlego.get(i).getMonto();
            String titulo = elSaldoPositivoQueLlego.get(i).getTitulo();
            String descripcion = elSaldoPositivoQueLlego.get(i).getDescripcion();
            montosPositivos[i] = String.valueOf(monto);
            montosPositivos[i] = titulo;
            montosPositivos[i] = descripcion;
            resultado = monto + resultado;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < elSaldoNegativoQueLlego.size(); j++) {
            double monto = elSaldoNegativoQueLlego.get(j).getMonto();
            String titulo = elSaldoNegativoQueLlego.get(j).getTitulo();
            String descripcion = elSaldoNegativoQueLlego.get(j).getDescripcion();
            montosNegativos[j] = String.valueOf(monto);
            montosNegativos[j] = titulo;
            montosNegativos[j] = descripcion;
            resultado2 = monto + resultado;
        }
        double total = resultado + resultado2;
        totalSaldo.setText("$ " + total);

        if (!elSaldoPositivoQueLlego.isEmpty()) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, montosPositivos);
            listaSaldosPositivos.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        } else {
            if (!elSaldoNegativoQueLlego.isEmpty()) {
                ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, montosNegativos);
                listaSaldosNegativos.setAdapter(itemsAdapter2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y esta es la clase secundaria de donde me estoy trayendo los datos para mostrar en las `ListView`:

```
public class nuevoSaldo extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_saldo);

    final EditText saldoIngresado = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSaldoIngresado);
    final EditText tituloIngresado = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTituloIngresado);
    final EditText descripcionSaldo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDescripcionSaldo);
    final RadioButton ingreso = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioBotonIngreso);
    final RadioButton gasto = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioBotonGasto);
    final Button añadir = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonAñadirMontoNegativoOPositivo);
    final Button cancelar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonCancelarNuevoSaldo);

    final ArrayList <Saldo> saldoIngreso = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList <Saldo> saldoGasto = new ArrayList<>();

    final Intent irAInicio = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),PaginaInicio.class);
    añadir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Saldo elSaldo = new Saldo();
            double saldo = Double.parseDouble(saldoIngresado.getText().toString());
            String titulo = tituloIngresado.getText().toString();
            String descripcion = descripcionSaldo.getText().toString();

            if (ingreso.isChecked()) {
                elSaldo.setMonto(saldo);
                elSaldo.setTitulo(titulo);
                elSaldo.setDescripcion(descripcion);
                saldoIngreso.add(elSaldo);
           }else {
               if(gasto.isChecked()){
                    elSaldo.setMonto(saldo);
                    elSaldo.setTitulo(titulo);
                    elSaldo.setDescripcion(descripcion);
                saldoGasto.add(elSaldo);
            }
            }
            saldoIngresado.setText("");
            tituloIngresado.setText("");
            descripcionSaldo.setText("");
            irAInicio.putExtra("saldosPositivos", saldoIngreso);
            irAInicio.putExtra("saldosNegativos", saldoGasto);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Monto agregado con éxito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(irAInicio);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Hacer una depuración y compartir la excepción que se muestra cuando la aplicación se detiene sería una gran ayuda en encontrar el error.

Answer (score 0):

hijo te esta complicando la vida...

Usar el Intent no es seguro..por que cuando quieres volver a la actividad anterior los datos se pierden..

**sugerencia**...te **recomiendo** usar clases genéricas..para enviar tus datos y obtenerlos desde el Adaptador.

Aquí un buen ejemplo...

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: Que exactamente no es seguro usando un intent? Con un `Intent` se pueden pasar datos en el `bundle` y también se pueden crear `Intent` con resultados. No crees que tu respuesta es demasiado genérico?